# smtplib sendmail in python fails SMTPHeloError: (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid Address')

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
import smtplib
my_address = 'myaddress@msn.com'
hears = [ 'Subject: A test',
      'From: ' + my_address,
      'To: ' + my_address,
      ]
entries = "Hello"
msg ='r\n'.join(hears) + 'r\n' + ' '.join(entries)
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
smtp.starttls('smtp.live.com')
smtp.sendmail(my_address, [my_address] , msg)
smtp.close()
```

I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\sssemail.py", line 11, in <module>
smtp.starttls('smtp.live.com')
File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in starttls
self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 553, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
raise SMTPHeloError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid Address')
```

Can any one give me insight on what is happening?

Comment: Why are you passing a host name to starttls()?

Comment: Welcome to the community, remember to word the title of your question in a question rather than just printing out the error. It makes it easier for everyone to help.

Comment: You miss a backslash from your `'\r\n'`s.

Comment: Thank-you. I added the \ and commented out starttls() and ran the code again and still got the same error. The outlook.com documentation states that I have to specify the tls option.